# MYSQL after QA Migration to Maria DB, application query returns different cases for a column result set meta data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Were attempting to migrate some mysql servers to MariaDB on a new AWS (amazon-linux-2) instance.
After creating a new instance and installing mariadb we've dumped the old database via
`mysqldump ... --add-drop-database --triggers --routines --events`
and imported into the new system using
`mysql -u root < dump.sql`

The database has a table defined with mixture of uppercase and lower case columns e.g `COLUMN1,COLUMN2,column3,etc`

The original database, via `mysqld -V`, is `mysqld  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for Linux (x86_64)`

The new database is, via `mysqld -V`, is `mysqld  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)`
installed with `yum install mariadb-server`

I've verified the schema's columns match for the table in question.

The accessing application queries the table with a select statement requesting the columns as lowercase.
(I've connected a local application and tested executing the same query against both database)

e.g. `SELECT column1,column2,column3,etc from TABLE1 where ..`

The results from the query from the original database respect the casing in the "select" statement from the application, however in the new mariadb database, the query results match the column casing as defined in the table.

Is there a setting that can be applied that will cause the result column names to respect the casing in the "SELECT" statement, and therefore cause the result column names returned by the same select statement in both databases to match?

A testcase under MariaDB and Mysql

```
select cname from (select s.CName from (select 'A' as CNAME) s) t;
```

Under MariaDB the result set column casing matches the column from the intermediary temp table.

[image: Results column case follows Intermediary table column casing]

With the same query using the source mysql database,

[image: MySQL Query Results columns match the case of the selection]

The result set column name's casing matches the casing in the select statement

Comment: Mysql -V gives you the version of the mysql cli, not the version of the server...

Comment: I'm surprised that this anomaly exists but, as a workaround, presumably you could alias the column names?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bad practice not to use coding styles for SQL and mixing lowercase, uppercase or mixed case identifiers ("It was hard to write, therefore it should be hard to read"). There are several coding style guidelines, e.g. [SQL Style Guide](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/business-ops/data-team/sql-style-guide/).

Beside that, you should also consider to upgrade to a more recent version of MariaDB/MySQL. MariaDB 5.5 will be eoled in 3 months.

But back to your problem:

Column identifiers are case insensitive, therefore the optimizer recognizes that your SQL statement can be simplified, in more recent versions of MariaDB the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and `SHOW WARNINGS` commands will give you more information:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select version();
+--------------------------+
| version()                |
+--------------------------+
| 10.5.1-MariaDB-debug-log |
+--------------------------+
MariaDB [(none)]> explain extended select cname from (select s.CName from (select 'A' as CNAME) s) t;
+------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1    |   100.00 |                |
|    3 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | No tables used |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                        |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select 'A' AS `CName` from dual |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, the statement was optimized and transformed to `` select 'A' AS `CName` from dual ``.

Obviously in MariaDB 5.5 the optimizer was already more modern than the MySQL optimizer, but in recent version of MySQL you will get the same result:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.13    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> explain select cname from (select s.CName from (select 'A' as CNAME) s) t;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | NULL       | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL           |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL       | NULL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | No tables used |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                        |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select 'A' AS `CName` from dual |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, mixed case is not ideal. I can modify he installing database and configuration, but not the application or the schema on which it depends. It sounds like I may need to go with the source mysql version, and get a change request started to explicitly alias the columns of the query in question for a future software release.

Comment: I don't know anything about your application or which database driver it is using, but this problem could be easily resolved by having a client option which specifies to return column names metadata always in lowercase.

Comment: That would break other parts of the app. The app expects the column names to be returned in the case specified by the the query, the behavior in MySQL 5.5.